# How to draw roads?

Tags: vector, cs6, adobe-fireworks, maps, path-effects

How to draw roads in fireworks cs6?

In the next way:
I paint a line/path and I obtain two paralell lines/paths
Pasing from
[image]

To
[image]

And changing the "roads" with the central/path of the "roads"
[image]

This is very well explained for illustrator in this video
https://youtu.be/fIJeGM2VOzM?t=464

How do I do this in Adobe Fireworks? If it's possible.

Comment: Please don't make me sit through a video to try and figure out what you are asking. Can you explain what it is you are having trouble with? Be aware Fireworks has been dead for a number of years... and it never had an Appearance Panel like Illustrator has.

Comment: @Scott You mustn´t show it. You have the images. The video is a plus!! not necessary. Yes, I know that Fireworks hasn´t new versions!

Comment: Okay, well. I can not figure out what your question is based upon the images. Please put a *little* effort into *explaining* your question. Thank you.

Comment: @Scott I had put more than a little effort. If you can´t undestand, don´t worry! Another choice is viewing 4 seconds the video. That´s faster than write any of the previous comments. The video is located in the exact time where you can see what I´m intested in.

Comment: The point is that this is not how this site works. If the video gets removed there is no question as a future reference.

Comment: The question is complete. The video is a plus/add. The video is no necessary for the question.

Answer (score 3):

One option (without seeing the video) is:

Make two layers. In the superior layer put the white part of the road, let's say you use a width of 1mm.

Copy the layer and put it below the previous one and on this layer use a black stroke of 2 mm.