# How to design simple highway?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, drawing

I'm looking for is a website or software to design 3D or 2D draft for a highway.

Like this one:
[image]

Or this:

[image]

My main intention is to draw a highway with exits, road signs, ground directions signs, trees and main exit signs.

I know it's graphics design but since it has traffic design I didn't know which section fit the topics related to traffic design.

I'm actually looking for a very simple software or website to put the basic blocks of the design. But anyway I wanted it for students final project report to implement the design of the project idea, I just grabbed a picture from Google images and implemented it in the powerpoint, I knew it would take me a lot of time to find what I'm looking for where it's a very simple thing, and not important to me, of course it could be effective if the report is professional.

Comment: neither one of those images are suitable for civil engineering

Comment: Then thats graphic design not civil engineering [this is what civil engineering looks like](https://damassets.autodesk.net/content/dam/autodesk/www/products/autodesk-autocad-civil-3d/responsive-center/images/features/2016/construction-documentation-enhanced-large-1152x750.jpg)

Comment: What software do you know how to use?

Comment: OK, I know civil engineering takes a lot of topics, that why I found it hard to describe the relationship to my actual topic. I know it's graphics design but since it has traffic design I didn't know which section fit the topics related to traffic design.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a very simple software or website to put the basic blocks of the design. But anyway I wanted it for students final project report to implement the design of the project idea, I just grabbed a picture from Google images and implemented it in the powerpoint, I knew it would take me a lot of time to find what I'm looking for where it's a very simple thing, and not important to me, of course it could be effective if the report is professional.

Comment: Get Cities skylines it has nice and easy road design system

Comment: Well you could actually write what you ACTUALLY want

Comment: I watched the youtube video about this software it looks really interesting! Thanks again :)

Comment: "Well you could actually write what you ACTUALLY want", how? That was my best to describe what I want.

Comment: Explain what you need it for! Remeber comments are not permanent they will get deleted.

Comment: OK, thanks, now I can delete the unnecessary comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is for students, a good call is for free software.

Then your option is Inkscape, that can draw the examples you posted very easy... and it is free.

IF you want a real 3D program, also free go for Blender or Sketchup... Did I mention free?

And those are really good programs. I think an important part of the assignment is to use legal software.

---

Illustrator can be used for free for some days, and the subscription plan is not that expensive. That is an option.

Another option is the student's discount on Corel Draw. It costs about 20% of the normal price.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The Inkscape looks good, it needs some drawing skills, as the students actually lack a lot of skills even with powerpoint which is a very good platform to do a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator can have multiple strokes for a single path, so generally you could have a line, like a road, then add the tarmac as a stroke, the sides as another stroke and so on. There are some limitations but this is generally a good method of building similar artwork. See this:

- [Drawing Roads on Simple Maps in Illustrator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIJeGM2VOzM)
- [How to draw roads?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110035/how-to-draw-roads)
- [How to Create Roads and Rail Tracks on a Path](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-roads-and-rail-tracks-on-a-path--vector-3227)

[image]

Comment: I tried to do something in powerpoint, I got the basic sketch of the highway. But, then the other stuff comes; like, exit lines, road signs, trees and any other aesthetic things to add to the design, so it appeared to be a lot of work in powerpoint so I deleted it and just took a picture of Google images and pointed the main points about the project. But the software provided my Mr @joojaa is wonderful it would really solve the problem but the report isn't so important to purchase the software.

Comment: No tools, no fire.. Adobe Illustrator comes with a 30-day free trial. Powerpoint not likely to get this done.